# PowerShell Replace CRLF in certain scenarios

Tags: file, powershell, replace, newline

I'm new to PowerShell and wish to replace CRLF in some scenarios within a textfile.

An Example textfile will be:

```
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3
List asd asd
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3
Sometest asd asd
Begin 1 2 3
```

Where a line isn't starting with Begin or End, I wish to append that line onto the previous one.

So the desired outcome would be:

```
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3 List asd asd
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3 Sometest asd asd
Begin 1 2 3
```

The file is Tab Seperated. So after Begin and End, is a TAB.

I tried the below, just to get rid of all the CRLF's, which doesn't work:

```
$content = Get-Content c:\test.txt
$content -replace "'r'n","" | Set-Content c:\test2.txt
```

I've read the MSDN on PowerShell and can replace text on different lines, just not over multiple lines like this :(

I'm at home testing on Windows 7, but this is for work and will be on Vista.

Comment: I realise now, that Get-Content reads in the file, in lines of strings and removed the CRLF? - I can use something like this though: [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\test.txt") -replace "`r`n[^B | ^E]","" | Set-Content c:\test2.txt

But this removed the L and S, on List and Sometest

Comment: Note that `$content` is an array.  You can convince yourself by trying `$content.GetType()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this one line ?

```
gc "beginend.txt" | % {}{if(($_ -match "^End")-or($_ -match "^Begin")){write-host "`n$_ " -nonewline}else{write-host $_ -nonewline}}{"`n"}

Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3 List asd asd
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3
Begin 1 2 3
End 1 2 3 Sometest asd asd
Begin 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# read the file
$content = Get-Content file.txt

# Create a new variable (array) to hold the new content
$newContent = @()

# loop over the file content    
for($i=0; $i -lt $content.count; $i++)
{  
  # if the current line doesn't begin with 'begin' or 'end'   
  # append it to the last line םכ the new content variable
  if($content[$i] -notmatch '^(begin|end)')
  {
    $newContent[-1] = $content[$i-1]+' '+$content[$i]
  } 
  else
  {
    $newContent += $content[$i]
  }
}

$newContent
```

Comment: Could you provide some background/context against this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = gc "beginend.txt"

$start = ""
foreach($line in $data) {
    if($line -match "^(Begin|End)") {
        if($start -ne "") {
            write-output $start
        }
        $start = $line
    } else {
        $start = $start + " " + $line
    }
}

# This last part is a bit of a hack.  It picks up the last line
# if the last line begins with Begin or End.  Otherwise, the loop
# above would skip the last line.  Probably a more elegant way to 
# do it :-)
if($data[-1] -match "^(Begin|End)") {
    write-output $data[-1]
}
```